# Language of tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that some of the tags are in English, for example, [preposition](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preposition) and [culture](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) and some are in Esperanto, for example, [volativo](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volativo) and [muziko](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muziko). This seems like it will produce a lot of duplicate tags, and difficulty in searching and filtering effectively. Should there be a standard for what language the tags should be in?

Comment: Moderators will be able to set tag synonyms, allowing a complete set of Esperanto-language tags to exist in the system and point to the "standard" English-language tags (or vice versa).

Comment: Tag synonyms are not used to have bilingual tags. Their purpose is totally different.

Answer (score 5):

I'm starting to think we should rename all of the tags to Esperanto. In the Spanish, French and Portuguese StackExchanges the tags are all in their respective languages and have descriptions in that language too. There appear to be aliases for the tag names in English.

It's interesting that on those sites there are many more questions that are *in* the language of the site. If we rename the tags this might encourage more people to ask in Esperanto and then the site would be more accessible to people who don't have such a good command of English.

Comment: The grammar terms of Bertilo such as "o-vorto" and "vorteto" are also simpler to understand.

Comment: The only sites not using English tags are probably the sites for which the site language isn't English. I am not sure that having questions all in Esperanto would help users who are learning Esperanto. Differently from Esperanto, English is taught as foreign language in many schools.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that in general we should stick with using tags in English, except in the case an Esperanto word is more appropriate because it expresses a concept that is otherwise difficult to express with an English word.

I would rather avoid using [volativo](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volativo) and [muziko](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muziko).

Keep in mind that EL, like many other Stack Exchange sites, is an English site. Questions in Esperanto are allowed, but the site language is still English. The site is not even prepared to handle diacritics in tags, and probably also the algorithm to detect low quality questions need to be calibrated for a language different from English.

Answer (score 2):

It feels natural to me to use some tags in Esperanto, such as muziko. Especially since those probably are topics we'd talk about in Esperanto...

Comment: All the topics on _Esperanto Language_ are about Esperanto. Other questions about other languages are off-topic.

Comment: Not "about" Esperanto - *in* Esperanto. As in per Esperanto, using the language.

Comment: Since the  topic is Esperanto, you cannot  ask a question about a song in Chinese, or Chinese music. So, the distinction between [tag:music] and [tag:musiko] doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't think it is essential that it should be muziko, I was just trying to explain why it feels like a natural tag to me rather than "music". I don't think you have understood what I mean, so I'll try to clarify. Some questions are going to be in Esperanto, some in English. It feels to me as if the questions IN Esperanto logically should have tags as well IN Esperanto. (There are other reasons why all tags should be in English). The music that people ask about should logically be in Esperanto, but my comment is about the language used to ask the question.

Comment: The language used to ask a question doesn't change the subject of a question. Plus, it is not like we have users who would be able to answer a question tagged [tag:musiko], but not questions tagged [tag:music]. As most of the Stack Exchange sites, also EL is an English site which just allows to ask questions in Esperanto too. It is not an Esperanto site about Esperanto.

Answer (score 0):

How about bilingual tag names in the style `Esperanto tag name — english tag name`?

So we'd change [muziko](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muziko) to **muziko — music**, etc.

For accessibility, we'd have to add both Esperanto-only and English-only synonyms, both redirecting to the bilingual tag.

Off course, we'd probably want to have diacritics support in the tags first, or we'd have to use the x- or h-notation for them which looks kinda unpolished.

Comment: Hmm ... seems like tags also support no spaces, so this might not be feasible.

Comment: There is a [Q&A on the main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309032/282094), if you have a solution for that question, or new question that is applicable to multiple sites, you can answer/ask there.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. Done: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330055/285037

Comment: Congratulations, your write-up on Meta seems to be gaining some support. You might write on German/Spanish Meta and mention your Main Meta post; to draw more votes.